# calling CUDA compiled .dll from R - .C vs .Call

Tags: c++, c, r, cuda

By following [this NVidia blog entry](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/) I have created a CUDA function under Windows 7 x64 dll. The function is defined as follows:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void gvectorAdd(double *A, double *B, double *C, int *n)
```

I can call this successfuly from within R (v3.2.3 64bit) using the following:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(5,6,7,8)
c <- c(0,0,0,0)
n <- length(c)

path.dll <- "cuda_r_1.dll"
dyn.load(path.dll)

c <- .C("gvectorAdd", 
        as.numeric(a), 
        as.numeric(b), 
        as.numeric(c), 
        as.integer(n),
        PACKAGE="cuda_r_1"
      )[[3]]
```

I believe that I should be using `.Call` instead of `.C`. However, when I replace `.C(...)` with `.Call(...)` in the above code the R session crashes.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should prefer using `.Call`, but the `.C` and `.Call` interfaces are different -- `.Call` expects `SEXP`s for all arguments. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eCall-and-_002eExternal for some more details. In other words, you'll need to change the `gvectorAdd` function if you want to move to the `.Call` interface.

Comment: @KevinUshey: That sounds like a perfectly good answer if you want to add it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prefer using `.Call`, but the `.C` and `.Call` interfaces are different -- `.Call` expects SEXPs for all arguments. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eCall-and-_002eExternal for some more details.

In other words, you'll need to change the `gvectorAdd` function if you want to move to the `.Call` interface.